# SIMBA ODBC DRIVER

Tags: google-bigquery

I have installed the ODBC driver and configred the linked server to be used in MS SQL SERVER.
in the driver , I have enabled high throughput API and the google storage API is enabled for my project.

A/c to the documentation, BigQueryHTAPI_sb[Bitness].dll should be in the same directory as the driver. 
My driver is installed in C:\Program Files\Simba ODBC Driver for Google BigQuery\

but I don't see the BigQueryHTAPI_sb64.dll in the lib dir .
Am I missing something? does the dll get installed during the driver installation?

the documentation I followed is here ..
https://www.simba.com/products/BigQuery/doc/ODBC_InstallGuide/win/content/odbc/bq/windows/ht-api.htm

Kindly let me know what I am missing here?

To configure the High-Throughput API:

Make sure that your Google BigQuery project has the Storage API enabled. For more information about the Storage API, see "BigQuery Storage API Overview" in the Google BigQuery documentation: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/storage/.
Make sure that the High-Throughput API library, BigQueryHTAPI_sb[Bitness].dll, is in the same directory as the driver.

Answer (score 0):

The `BigQueryHTAPI_sb[Bitness].dll` file is removed in the latest version (2.2.5.1012) of the [Simba ODBC drivers for Google BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/providers/simba-drivers) and merged into the main driver DLL.